# Need to change an element of a multidimensional string vector in C++

Tags: vector

I have a multidimensional string vector, gameState.  The contents of gameState can be seen below.  I would like to "move" A up one space by making [2][1] = " " and [1][1] = "A". But I'm getting an error (error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traitsstd::allocator<char, char>::value_type' {aka 'char'} [-fpermissive]).  Not sure if there is a way to use vector.at() in this case.  Here is a snippet.  The full code reads in the initial game state from a text file and assigns it to the string vector gameState.  I get the row and col indexes for each letter in the grid below and assign them to variables (eg. Arow and Acol).  I'm very new to C++, so any help would be appreciated.  If you have any questions about the rest of the code, I'd be happy to elaborate.  Thanks in advance.

```
int Arow;
int Acol;
vector<string> gameState;
string tempU = gameState[Arow-1][Acol];

if (tempU != "#") {
                // if no wall is up, move up
                gameState[Arow][Acol] = " ";
                gameState[Arow-1][Acol] = "A";
                Arow = Arow-1;
                Amovesequence.push_back("U");
}

###########
#...#P...B#
#A#.$.###*#
#...#D...R#
###########
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of `gameState[Arow-1][Acol]` is a char, not a string. Modify the code accordingly, e.g.: `char tempU = ...` and replace `" "` with `' '`etc.